# How can I update rails older version to new version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my system I have rails 4.2.5 
and ruby 2.2.3.

how can I update to rails 5.0.0.beta version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade instructions for the current beta are available [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html).

You need to have a test suite with good coverage before you begin. Run `rake rails:update` to update your configs. You also need to follow the instructions on the upgrade page, which include changing class names to the ones that are currently in use.